# Saving POST data for later purpose

Tags: php, forms, back

I use 2 forms so that users can filter a table or search data in the table :
there's a search input text field,
2 date input
a search by statut

By default the page display all the result. There are links in the table and what I would is that after clicking on a link and then clicking the back button, user's selection is recalled. I know it's something you find quite often but I don't know how to do it the right way and I don't know how to search more informations on the subject

I tried to achieve this using sessions but it's messy. I'd like to find a clean way to do this and not use a thousand of if conditions. I'm already not to proud of my code because there are a already to much conditions and functions to do what I want

```php
// recherche par nom, code magasin
if(isset($_POST['search_form']))
{
    $fAllActive=search($pdoLitige);
    $nbLitiges=count($fAllActive);
    $valoTotal=searchValo($pdoLitige);
    $valoEtat=searchGpType($pdoLitige);
}
elseif(isset($_POST['filter']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['etat']))
    {
        $fAllActive=filter($pdoLitige);
        $valoTotal=getSumValoFilter($pdoLitige);
        $valoEtat=getSumValoFilterGpType($pdoLitige);
    }
    else
    {
        $fAllActive=filterJustDate($pdoLitige);
        $valoTotal=getSumValoJustDate($pdoLitige);
        $valoEtat=getSumValoJustDateGpType($pdoLitige);

    }
    $nbLitiges=count($fAllActive);
}
else
{
    //affichage par défaut : totalite de la base pour l'année en cours
        $fAllActive=getAllDossier($pdoLitige);
    $nbLitiges=count($fAllActive);
    $valoTotal=getSumValoAll($pdoLitige);
    $valoEtat=getSumValoAllGpType($pdoLitige);
}
```

Comment: why you pass these params this via POST? use GET so user can bookmark it easily and you do not need to bother

Comment: You're so right, I don't need POST at all in this case !... I'm used to use post method so I can save data to mysql. I didn't think about using get. Thank you so much !